# Not able to debug Express REST API in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webstorm, javascript-debugger

I have created an Express REST API and followed various methods to put debugger inside API callback function, but no luck. I also tried [This link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/). Still I am not able to use debugger on API call. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally all you need to do to get such breakpoints hit is starting your **Node.js** run configuration in debugger and then opening `<yourserver URL>/list` in browser:

[image]